# chromecast not showing smooth NFL Game pass tab

Tags: hdmi, google-chrome-extensions, chromecast

I've purchased a ChromeCast just to view NFL Game-Pass on my TV (since I'm nor in the US, Hulu and Netflix are not an option). However it doesn't cast the game smoothly. I've tried lowering the rate to 480p to no avail. My laptop when sitting next to the TV can show full BandWidth (4Mbps according to the NFL app) and the view is smooth and great on my full HD TV (connected with HDMI cable). Both the laptop and TV are about 3 meters from the WiFi router. I've also tried to cast while the laptop is connected to the network with cable (not wifi) . didn't help. My Laptop is a Lenovo think-pad edge with Ubuntu 12.10 and chrome version 30.0.1599.114 (I had to upgrade it manually).

BTW: I've contacted Google but don't expect them to answer any time soon (or at all...)
Any more suggestions?

Comment: This is a user experience issue.

Answer (score 2):

When Game Pass opens in the pop-up browser, it also has a hyperlink. Copy/Paste that hyperlink into a normal Chrome browser that has the Chromecast button. Voila! It's not 120Hz smooth, but the audio/video sync perfectly and it works great.

Comment: thanks for answering. But I tried that and it doesn't work for me... I get about 1 frame per 5 seconds and jumps in sound as well... Any more suggestions?